# Error 415 when posting JSON data to WCF Service

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest

I am trying to send some JSON data to a service I have created in c# and wcf. In Fiddler my POST request is as follows

Fiddler:

```
Request Header
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 29
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Request Body
{sn:"2705", modelCode:1702 }
```

Below is the service interface. That uses the WebInvoke attribute to manage the POST request

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IProjectorService
{
    [WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate="projectors", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json )]
    [OperationContract]
    void RecordBreakdown(Record record);
}
```

The implementation of the service interface takes the variables passed in to the argument and uses ado to send this data to a SQL db.

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public partial class ProjectorService : IProjectorService
{

    public void RecordBreakdown(Record record)
    {
        //ado code to send data to db (ie do record.SerialNumber...
    }        
}
```

POCO object to represent the multiple parameters

```
[DataContract]
public class Record
{      
    [DataMember]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ModelCode { get; set; }
}
```

.svc file

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="ProjectorService" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/ProjectorService.cs" %>
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In fiddler, when I click on "execute", I receive an error 415 "unsupported media type". My current line of thought is that in my Projector service class, maybe im supposed to create a response object and send the 200 code back?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a WCF endpoint to recognize the `[WebInvoke]` (or `[WebGet]`) annotations, it needs to be defined as a WebHTTP endpoint (a.k.a. REST endpoint) - which means using the `webHttpBinding` and the `webHttp` endpoint behavior. Since you didn't define any endpoints in web.config, it is using the default binding for the scheme, which is `BasicHttpBinding`. Endpoints with that binding only respond to XML (SOAP) requests, which is why you're getting that error when sending a JSON request.

Try replacing your `<system.serviceModel>` section in your web.config, and that should define your endpoint as you need it:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="ProjectorService">
        <endpoint address=""
                  behaviorConfiguration="Web"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="IProjectorService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thats worked. I thought the web binding was automatically generated using a factory method in the svc file (which I hadnt included anyway). As well as these changes i needed to ad the `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` to the service method as the JSON data wasn't wrapped in another object.

Comment: this works well for getting JSON response from wcf service

Answer (score 5):

The problem is most likely that your service method requires 2 parameters. Default only 1 body parameter can be present.

You can fix this in 2 ways. 
First way: 
Add *BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped* to your WebInvoke Attributes like so:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "projectors", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
void RecordBreakdown(string sn, int modelCode);
```

Second way: Create a class for the POST data. You can for example create a class for all the variables you want to post to your service as JSON. To create classes from JSON you can use [Json2CSharp](http://json2csharp.com/) (or Paste JSON as Classes in VS2012 Update 2). 
The following JSON

```
{"sn":2705, "modelCode":1702 }
```

will result in the following class:

```
public class Record
{
    public string sn { get; set; }
    public int modelCode { get; set; }
}
```

After that you will have to change your methods to accept this class like so:

```
void RecordBreakdown(string sn, int modelCode);
```

to:

```
void RecordBreakdown(Record record);
```

After that you now should be able to post JSON to the service.

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**
Joining my answer from below with this one.

After looking again to your configuration file, it also looks like a binding misconfiguration. The default binding for WCF is a 'bassicHttpBinding' which is basically using SOAP 1.1.

Since you want to use JSON and a RESTFul service you will have to use a 'webHttpBinding'.  [Here is a link](http://pastebin.com/Yj4bdrHp) to a basic configuration we are always using for our RESTFul services. You can set the security mode to Transport when secure transport (f.e.: https) is needed.

```
<security mode="Transport"></security>
```

Comment: I have tried adding BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped but it hasn't worked. Still getting a 415 error. I have also removed the multiple parameters and created a new class based on your suggestion, I prefer this way I think so i have updated the question to show these changes, but this too doesnt work im still seeing error 415.

Comment: After looking again to your configuration file, it also looks like a binding misconfiguration. The default binding for WCF is a 'bassicHttpBinding' which is basically using SOAP 1.1. Since you want to use JSON and a RESTFul service you will have to use a 'webHttpBinding'. I've included a link to a basic configuration we are always using for our RESTFul services. :) Info: [link](http://pastebin.com/Yj4bdrHp)